# PHP Redis (predis) counter with unique currently viewers

Tags: php, redis, counter

I would like to know how to implement a unique visitor counter using [Redis](https://redis.io/) with a timeout of 1 hour.  I have a little online shop and I would like to show how many guys are viewing an article currently. What would be the best way? I'm using [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis)

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do 2 things:

- Generate a unique ID for each visitor (they [**are many ways to do it**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=visitor%20unique%20id))
- Use a Redis `SET` or `ZSET` to store those ids and add an expire mechanism.

#### Method #1: SET + SCARD + EXPIRE

**Solution**

The SET name could be something like `[article_id]:[current_hour_timestamp]`, each time you `SADD` a visitor id inside it, do an `EXPIRE`. Each set will expire after a certain time.

Use `SCARD [article_id]:[current_hour_timestamp]` to know how many visitors are online

**Notes**

The key can be `[article_id]:[current_hour_timestamp]` or anything like `articles:[article_id]:readers:[current_hour_timestamp]` if you prefer...

At every hour start the SET will be empty that's not what you may want.

#### Method #2: ZSET + ZCARD + cron

**Solution**

Each time a visitor read open an article send a `ZADD [article_id]:readers [expiry_time] [visitor_id]`, it does not matter if it reload the page, the `expiry_time` will just be updated.

`expiry_time` is the timestamp in the future when we consider the visitor to have leaved the article.

Setup a cron to run each hour:

```
Retrieve all article ids in databases
For each article
 Send a `zremrangebyscore "article.id:readers" -inf [current_timestamp]` to remove expired visitors_id
```

Finally to retrieve current readers count run `ZCARD [article_id]:readers`.

**Note**

This approach is way better because it uses a sliding window so you won't have the "0 reader" effect at each new hour. However the downside is that you will need to loop over all your article id which could be an issue.

#### Method #3: ZSET + ZCARD + ZSET as index + cron

**Solution**

Same as method #2, however this one uses another zset `articles:readers:zset` that contains all zset keys recently updated.

You will then have to loop through this zset members instead of all article ids.

**Note**

If you go down that way don't forget to remove expired members from `articles:readers:zset` !